Understanding Power Bi Server Log files
I have a requirement to diagnose performance issues on one of our Power Bi Servers. We've enabled verbose logging but I can't find information anywhere about that the trace and info numbers mean in the log file. Does anybody know or have a reference for what the numbers mean after the TRACE and INFO etc identifiers.. i.e. |TRACE|62| or |INFO|88|
This information is in the RSPowerBI_2024_11_13_07_03_46.log
11-13 14:01:28.8177|TRACE|62|Sending response. R..........
2024-11-13 14:01:29.0052|TRACE|76|Sending response.................
2024-11-13 14:01:44.7764|TRACE|6|Sending response. .................
2024-11-13 14:01:44.8388|INFO|88|Received request GET /libs/scrip..........
2024-11-13 14:01:44.8388|TRACE|88|Processing custom header rule X....
2024-11-13 14:01:44.8388|TRACE|88|Processing custom header rule X......
2024-11-13 14:01:45.0577|INFO|88|Received request GET /sandbox..........
2024-11-13 14:01:45.0577|TRACE|88|Processing custom header rule X-.........
2024-11-13 14:01:45.0577|TRACE|88|Processing custom header rule X-.........
2024-11-13 14:01:45.0577|TRACE|68|Sending response. Response code...........
2024-11-13 14:01:45.0577|TRACE|12|Sending response. Response code........
I've trawled through all the information I can find relating to power bi logs and I can't find any information anywhere... Any help would be greatly appreciated.
